# Wordpress Custom loop with two types of posts with different amounts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a category names "notes", I need on every page of the loop to show up to 10 notes, and up to 4 regular posts.

They both should be ordered by date.

i.e. I posted 1 note, `note A`, 1 hour ago and another note, `note b`, 5 hours ago, I also posted to posts, `post A` and `post B` 2 hours ago. in my loop I want to see `note A`,`post A`,`post B`,`note B`.

I hope it's clear enough.

I'm trying to do this with two custom WP_Queries, but I have hard time with them because of the global `$post`.

Any help would do!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, if anyone is interested, this is how I did it:

```
<?php
function elis_sortbydate ($a, $b) {
$time_a = strtotime($a->post_date);
$time_b = strtotime($b->post_date);
if ($time_a == $time_b) return 0;
return ($time_a > $time_b) ? -1 : 1;
}
$query = array_merge(array('cat' => 67, 'posts_per_page=10'), $wp_query->query);
    $notes_query = new WP_Query($query);

    $query = array_merge(array('cat' => -67, 'posts_per_page=4'), $wp_query->query);
    $posts_query = new WP_Query($query);
    if ($notes_query->have_posts() and $posts_query->have_posts()) {
        $all_posts = array_merge($notes_query->posts, $posts_query->posts);
        usort($all_posts, "elis_sortbydate");
        foreach ($all_posts as $post) { ... }
            }
```

the resulting `$all_posts` array is sorted by date (from high to low)